# gmail settings for sending mail on mac

Tags: php, gmail

I'm using mac OS snow leopard, and i have probs with mail, i'm not sure is it something about gmail, or php mail() func.
It's not working. I wrote it this way (just for testing ).

```
mail('something@example.com', 'My Subject', 'My Message');
```

I done * i need with postfix configuration, but it's not working (can't get the mail).
Any help, just need explanation on how things work. I'm googling last 3-4 hours, but nothing (didn't find the right answer). And yes, i'm using local server.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your spam/junk folders?

Comment: Yes, nothing there. It's strange.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `From:` or `Reply-to:` field?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is hosted in local host the mails will not be able to send. Upload to a live server and check it. (You need a mail server to send the mails)

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip - if something isn't working, try and find the problem withing your code before blaming gmail or php functions. These have been tested and re-tested in live environments by literally millions of people.

Do you have a mail server installed and configured? Do you have Apache sendmail enabled?

Comment: I didn't blame them, i'm sorry for my english. I just ask question, i try a lot of things and my brain is like bubble gum. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Create a file (let's say info.php), and write in it `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Search for `sendmail` or `mail`. Do you find anything interesting ?

Comment: only - sendmail_from - no value, could that be a problem ?